# Load image to a label in userform using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a userform to load Images over labels, I am getting a

> Run time error '75': Path/File access error

with below code,

```
dim solArr as variant
solArr = Split("1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg",",")

For i = LBound(solArr) To UBound(solArr)
      'For rating image
      Dim ratingImageName As String
      ratingImageName = "D:\somepath" & "\" & solArr(i)
      Set imageStar = UserForm1.Frame3.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1")
      imageStar.Top = 40 + (i * 50)
      imageStar.Left = 420
      imageStar.Height = 20
      imageStar.Width = 100
      imageStar.Picture = LoadPicture(ratingImageName)
Next
```

But, if i use ratingImageName as `"D:\Somepath\1.jpg"` no error is recieved...
Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: `somepath` or `simepath` ?

Comment: `Debug.Print solArr(i)` what does it give?

Comment: Your `solArr = array(1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg)` line is not valid VBA.  Those values should be quoted.

Comment: `solArr = array("1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg")`?

Comment: Is this really your *exact* code?

Comment: @Chrismas007 it gives "1.jpg" the correct file name

Comment: let me edit and post the correct code....

Comment: When you split on the `,` is it getting caught in the array?

Comment: I am getting an error at line `imageStar.Picture = LoadPicture(ratingImageName)`

Comment: When it fails, what is the value of `ratingImageName` ?

Comment: @Tim `"D:\somepath\1.jpg"` ...

Comment: If it works with that same exact value hard-coded then it's unclear exactly what the issue is.

Comment: Please let me know if you could run the same code at your end and receives the error...thanks!

Comment: ok i encountered a strange behavior, if i use `on error resume next`, last image i.e. "3.jpg" is displayed properly...

Comment: *Only* the last image is displayed? If you reverse the order of the items in the array (and remove the `On Error Resume Next`) does the first image load?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.. `solArr = Array("1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg")`

Answer (score 0):

I was picking up a value from cell as

```
1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg
```

the sentence `replace(arrSol(i),chr(10),"")` solved the problem.

Comment: *Exact code* next time please!  Your question used a quoted string as the source: if you had included the step of fetching the value from a cell that would have been a huge help.

Answer (score -1):

```
Set imageStar = UserForm1.Frame3.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1")
```

I have an array of many items in-game. Example item1, item2, item3... How to change index at item (Exemple item & i) and add a picture it item in label in Form.

Comment: Is this an answer, or a new question? If you are asking a question, please post it as a question.